# Allocate a value on an object

Tags: javascript, jsonp, google-tag-manager

I have this quite simple code, that returns an object (at least in Google Chrome) from another (external) server, in the format of id:"12345676425432526".

How can i store this object value, so it can be accessible on the dom or though GTM. I just need to store the output as Global Value, with a code, not by Right click, store as a Global value. I want to use only JS and not Ajax or PHP or even Jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ABC = function(data) {
console.log(data);
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://externalsite.com/getid?callback=ABC">
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, AJAX is just a technology which is accessible from the Javascript language. They're not really different. Unless the external site provides a JSONP interface, you will require an AJAX call. No other possibility (within reason).

Comment: Thats not a codewriting service. What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is store that value in a cookie or local storage(only JS) and GTM can easily retrieve a value from 1st party cookie variable

Here is how you can learn a bit more about variables
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899?hl=en#web

Hope this helps,